# Cannot ValidateAndCreate model in gobuffalo

Tags: go, web-frameworks, buffalo

I am having trouble using pop.Connection#ValidateAndCreate in gobuffalo.

```
    purchaseOrder.Items = models.OrderItems{}

    ... fill purchaseOrder.Items ...

    for _, item := range purchaseOrder.Items {

        verrs, err := tx.ValidateAndCreate(item)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.WithStack(err)
        }

        if verrs != nil {
            // show error
        }
    }
```

`tx` is type *github.com/gobuffalo/pop.Connection

I get the error: `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value` on the line `verrs, err := tx.ValidateAndCreate(item)`

Comment: Most probably you need to pass a pointer to `ValidateAndCreate`, either define `OrderItems` as `[]*OrderItem`  instead of `[]OrderItem` (i assume that's how you've defined it), or use the address operator when passing item to `ValidateAndCreate`. E.g. `ValidateAndCreate(&item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ValidateAndCreate](https://godoc.org/github.com/gobuffalo/pop#Connection.ValidateAndCreate) requires the item as a pointer, since it needs to update the `ID` property in case it's auto-generated. Pop manages the `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` attributes too, so it have to change those too.

As proposed by mkopriva, you can change the `ValidateAndCreate` call to:

```golang
verrs, err := tx.ValidateAndCreate(&item)
if err != nil {
    return errors.WithStack(err)
}
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't just try that just to check. Thanks so much for your help!